# Получение и изменение координат курсора

Tags: c++, windows

Необходимо, чтобы программа, выполняясь в фоне, при зажатии ЛКМ перемещала курсор. Подскажите, как и с помощью чего это сделать на MS Windows?

Comment: хотя бы напишите, какая у вас ОС, тк то, что вы хотите сделать, возможно только средствами самой ОС.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вам потребуется WinAPI, язык сам по себе таких средств не представляет.

Для того, чтобы прочитать/записать позицию курсора, используйте [`GetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648390(v=vs.85).aspx)/[`SetCursorPos`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648394(v=vs.85).aspx).

Для того, чтобы узнать, когда нажата левая кнопка мыши, в *вашем* приложении, нужно обработать оконные сообщения `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` и `WM_LBUTTONUP` ([документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153548(v=vs.85).aspx)) в вашей оконной процедуре.

Если вы хотите обрабатывать и чужие приложения, вам нужно установить хук, подробнее об этом смотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10818037/276994).